# remove the 'page' URL parameter in previous/next posts link

Tags: links

I want to remove the "page" bit from the URL when I use the `previous_posts_link` and `next_posts_link`. Right now, it looks like:

http://mywebsite.com/page/2

I want it to look like this:

http://mywebsite.com/2

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yeah, got the tumbleweed badge :(. I ended up doing a 301 with the .htaccess, but If someone has a better idea please share it!